# ProjectLombok with Eclipse and Android

Tags: android, lombok

I am trying to use Lombok with Android however whenever I try to run I get these errors

```
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx] The library 'lombok2.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx] The following libraries were found:
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/freebsd-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/freebsd-i386/libjnidispatch.so
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/linux-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/linux-i386/libjnidispatch.so
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-amd64/libjnidispatch.so
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-sparc/libjnidispatch.so
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-sparcv9/libjnidispatch.so
[2012-02-10 10:53:49 - xxx]  - com/sun/jna/sunos-x86/libjnidispatch.so
```

I am trying to add lombok to an existing project ofmine that works flawlessly without lombok but lombok makes my life so much easier.

I installed the normal way (run the .jar file, then add it from `properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External Jar`) if you see a stupid error point it out! I would like to keep this app moving one of my teacher needs it in the next few weeks.

Thanks!

Comment: Lombok should not need any jars at runtime, the jars should not be copied into the project, i.e. not exported.

Comment: ok, then how do I import them into the projects? A little elaboration goes a long way.

Comment: Remove them from the Export in the Project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There apparently was an issue that was recently worked around by the Lombok people.  See http://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Run `java -jar lombok.jar publicApi` to create `lombok-api.jar`; it doesn't include any native libraries.

Reference: http://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html